# Hot Reload is not working in .net maui Using ios project

Tags: android, ios, .net, maui

## **I'm currently experiencing an issue when attempting to implement hot reload in my iOS project. I've followed the instructions provided by Microsoft, but it doesn't seem to be working for iOS. Are there any additional configurations or steps required specifically for iOS?**

```
HotReloadService.cs
#if DEBUG
[assembly: System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataUpdateHandlerAttribute(typeof(ThreadsApp.Helpers.HotReloadService))]
namespace ThreadsApp.Helpers;

public static class HotReloadService
{
#pragma warning disable CS8632 // The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' annotations context.
    public static event Action<Type[]?>? UpdateApplicationEvent;
#pragma warning restore CS8632 // The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' annotations context.

    internal static void ClearCache(Type[]? types) { }
    internal static void UpdateApplication(Type[]? types)
    {
        UpdateApplicationEvent?.Invoke(types);
    }
}
#endif

BasePage
using ThreadsApp.Helpers;

namespace ThreadsApp.Pages;

public abstract class BasePage : ContentPage
{
    public abstract void Build();

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);

        Build();
#if DEBUG
        HotReloadService.UpdateApplicationEvent += ReloadUI;
#endif
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigatedFromEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(args);

#if DEBUG
        HotReloadService.UpdateApplicationEvent -= ReloadUI;
#endif
    }

    private void ReloadUI(Type[] obj)
    {
        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            Build();
        });
    }
}
```

I've integrated this build into my iOS project and inherited the specified base class in my UI page instead of a ContentPage. However, when I make changes, no events seem to be firing in my iOS project.

I've also attempted to set up Hot Reload in the iOS Visual Studio preferences, but it hasn't resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As stated in MAUI Hot Reload document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/hot-reload?tabs=vswin), c# code hot reloading is not supported.

> XAML Hot Reload doesn't reload C# code, including event handlers.

From the description in your post, you are using [MetadataUpdateHandler to extend .NET Hot Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/hot-reload-metadataupdatehandler?view=vs-2022#additional-resources), it's a feature of VS. And I can reproduce the issue in iOS platform, it's recommended that you try to report the problem with VS(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)